# Rarely used translation function placement

Tags: interaction-design, layout, design-patterns, localization

I have just been looking at the analytics of one of the websites I work on, and one of the features is required - but rarely used. There is a Microsoft Translate button, with their "Powered by Microsoft Translator" on the page, which has been used 650 times out of 25,500 visits.

The placement is central, and directly underneath the item title, so I have no doubt that it is in a noticeable place, it just simply isn't being used.

I can't remove this, and my immediate thought was to put the functionality behind a translate icon, such as one here: http://thenounproject.com/tag/translate/

Any thoughts on this? Are there any other good patterns to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: You could get the language from the http request (or guess it from the IP), and add a little overlayed element to emphasize the translation option (a la google chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there a number of questions you should be asking yourself from multiple perspectives:

**Visual design**

1. Does the translate button stand out compared to the rest of the page, or does it get overshadowed by the rest of the content (such as the item title)?

**Demographics**

1. What are the demographics of the users who access your site? If it's mostly people who speak English (or what ever language the site is in), that could account for the low usage.
2. What type of browser do most of your users use? Google Chrome offers automatic translation using Google Translate, or at least offers to do it, so there might be a case where the users already see translated content when they come to the page.

**Textual translation of the content on the translate button**

1. I assume the text on the button says "Translate" or something like that. If the text is embedded in the image, then users might come to the page, understand nothing and might not be able to understand the translate button since it was in a language they don't understand at all.

With regards to using the translate icon, I don't recommend it since you could potentially cause confusion about what it means (there are some icons which are universal and accepted across the world but I doubt a translate icon is one of them). Another issue is that the icon might get lost in the page content (if the layout is not proper).

An approach to do the translate would be going with the approach which Google offers, that is to detect the language on the page and offer to translate it as shown below:

[image]

You will have to set the system to automatically determine the language based on the preferred language settings set in the system [like Chrome does](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1059490).